# Efficient delete of a tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a tree data structure :

- The root of the tree has no parents ans no previous siblings (it can
  have next siblings).
- Every node has a unique parent.
- Every node has a pointer to it's next and previous siblings, children and parent.

This tree data structure is being populated with millions of nodes. When I delete a tree having 
an enormous amount of nodes, a stack-overflow exception is thrown. The data structure works well when the number of nodes is relatively small or when I build in release mode.

This is the destructor of a node :

```
    Entity::~Entity(void)
    {
        Entity* child = NULL;

        if (firstChild != NULL)
            child = firstChild->getNextSibling();

        while(child != NULL)
        {
            delete child->getPreviousSibling();
            child->setPreviousSibling(NULL);

            child = child->getNextSibling();
        }

        if (lastChild != NULL)
            delete lastChild;

        if (isRoot())
        {
            if (nextSibling != NULL)
            {
                nextSibling->setPreviousSibling(NULL);
                delete nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }
```

One can implement a non recursive algorithm to traverse the tree and delete all it's nodes.

Could you suggest an efficient postorder traversal algorithm to delete a non binary tree ?

Comment: Another way (which does use extra memory) is to store a reference to all tree nodes in an array or in a dedicated linked list through the nodes and delete based on that instead of the tree structure.

Comment: You should leave your original code exposed, or the question can't be understood. The code that you now expose (without having accepted my answer), **don't** provoke any stack overflow, as you have tested.

Comment: The original code and your code does unfortunately provoke stack overflow. But your code is clearer ...

Comment: @chac I restored my original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Missed the bit about back-pointers to the parent node. That means we don't need to maintain a path history to backtrack, and we can do away with the stack.

```
node = root;
while (node)
{
    if (node->firstChild)
    {
        next = node->firstChild;
        node->firstChild = null;
    }
    else 
    {
        next = node->nextSibling ? node->nextSibling : node->parent;
        delete node;
    }
    node = next;
}
```

---

Original answer:

Anything you can do recursively, you can do with a loop and a stack. While this doesn't require any less memory, the advantage is that you can put that memory on the heap and avoid an overflow.

```
s.push(root);
while (!s.empty())
{
     node = s.pop();
     if (node->nextSibling) s.push(node->nextSibling);
     if (node->firstChild) s.push(node->firstChild);
     delete node;
}
```

Comment: I think this doesnt' work: when it goes back to parent, after deleted sons, it still has firstChild set, but pointing to freed node.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something much simpler, and let the recursive destructors do their duty:

```
Entity::~Entity(void)
{
    Entity* child = firstChild;
    while (child) {
      Entity *succ = child->getNextSibling();
      delete child;
      child = succ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is much more simpler then mine, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my particular problem.

Comment: I suggested this simplification because I was unsure of the correctness of your previous, especially the final part (something like delete lastChild...), and the stack usage it's very limited now: just 2 pointers * max_tree_deepth. Have you already verified the stack overflow?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I verified the stack overflow, and now it support much larger amount of nodes. I hope if someone come up with an iterative solution. Otherwise I will mark your solution as accepted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to `delete firstChild; delete nextSibling;`? Hopefully tail call optimisation will avoid the memory overhead of the second destructor call, so you end up with something equivalent to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sketch of a non-recursive solution:

- initialize a pointer to a node with the root pointer;
- repeat

  - if the current node has a son, move to that son;
  - else, delete the current node and return to its parent, if any;
- until the current node has no parent.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could simply increase your stack size.

On Windows and Visual C++, the default is paltry 1 MB - just increase it to 10 MB or even 100 MB - this memory won't actually be **committed** until (and unless) you actually need it, you'd just be **reserving** it up front (see the [/STACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option). You could even do it selectively for the Debug configuration only, to account for the "fatter" stack there.

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a static function to do the deletions. I've found in previous applications that asking a large tree of objects to do a task can be significantly slower than having an independent function perform the operation on the tree. A static function is essentially global, so the recursive call knows exactly where to go. Using a recursive "method" requires looking up the function through each object which could add extra overhead especially for cache-unfriendly operations like this. Along the same lines, you'll probably get better performance if you violate the interface to avoid the getNextSibling() call on each object and keep program flow completely in the one global recursive function.

It's not the recursion itself, it's that your instruction pipeline keeps stalling on data access as you run through this tree.

Comment: On second thought, a destructor look-up will have to be done regardless when you "delete". This could be avoided by linking them all together into a single list that is not actually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider whether you really need to bother walking the tree and processing each node.

I've frequently found it convenient to set up a dedicated memory pool for a particular task, and then free the entire pool at a stroke once it has completed.